# VBA: Authentication issues for PUT request

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble authenticating the below PUT request to the Freshdesk API v2 from Excel VBA. I'm new to this (VBA), but I think I'm SO CLOSE, can anyone tell me what's wrong with this code and why I'm getting a debug message saying

> {"code":"invalid_credentials","message":"You have to be logged in to perform this action."}?

```
Sub PutJSON()

  Dim URL As String
  Dim JSONString As String
  Dim objHTTP As New WinHttpRequest
  Dim token As String
  Dim response As String

  URL = "https://ourcompany.freshdesk.com/api/v2/time_entries/14001545629"
  token = "1234567890:X"

  objHTTP.Open "PUT", URL, False
  objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & token
  objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"

  JSONString = "{""billable"" : true, ""note"" : ""Updated from Excel!"", ""timer_running"" : false, ""agent_id"" : 14036310050, ""ticket_id"" : 37784, ""time_spent"" : ""02:00""}"
  objHTTP.send JSONString
  response = objHTTP.responseText

  Debug.Print response

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've cracked it. The API token was being handed in as a string, but it needed to be encoded as base64.

I used the following function I found:

```
Function EncodeBase64(text As String) As String
  Dim arrData() As Byte
  arrData = StrConv(text, vbFromUnicode)

  Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument
  Dim objNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement

  Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
  Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")

  objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
  objNode.nodeTypedValue = arrData
  EncodeBase64 = objNode.text

  Set objNode = Nothing
  Set objXML = Nothing

End Function
```

and changed the line

```
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & token
```

to

```
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & EncodeBase64(token)
```